# css make tbody same size as table

Tags: html, css, firefox

I can't get the `tbody` element to fully fill the `table` element:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS is:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
}

tbody {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
}
```

Resulting `table` dimensions (in firefox 56):

[image: rendered table dimensions]

Resulting `tbody` dimensions (in firefox 56):

[image]

This leaves a 2 pixel white border surrounding the contents of the table, that I want to get rid of. Is there some other CSS property that I need to zero out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of built in borders and border spacing.
To correct the issue add the `border-collapse: collapse;` style to the table.